# IIF statement with null value and multiple condition

Tags: reporting-services

I'm getting a problem with one of my expression in my report. It always gives me #Error and I think I know why but don't know how to set my expression.

Here's my expression :

```
=IIF(Fields!CMMTTEXT.Value.Contains("*Return*") AND Fields!SOPTYPE.Value = "INVOICE", "*** See return ***", "")
```

The Fields CMMTTEXT can be null sometimes and I'm getting an error on all of my rows except the one that has data in the CMMTTEXT field.

So I need a isnothing but I've tried couple ways of doing it but doens't seem to work

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!CMMTTEXT.Value.Contains("*Return*")) AND Fields!SOPTYPE.Value = "INVOICE", "*** See return ***", "")
```

also this that I've seen on this forum :

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!CMMTTEXT.Value) OR Fields!CMMTTEXT.Value.Contains("*Return*") AND Fields!SOPTYPE.Value = "INVOICE", "*** See return ***", "")
```

I have no idea at this point.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried `Fields!CMMTTEXT.Value = ""`?

Comment: Would have worked if it would have been only the word "Return" in the CMMTTEXT field but it can be a full sentence with the word "return" in it. Thats why it has to be a like/contain. Can't seem to figure out how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

The `Contains` function doesn't work with `NULL` values. Once it throws an error, the `IsNothing` function subsequently can't evaluate the results. Separating these out using the `OR` operator also doesn't work because it tries to evaluate both conditions even when the first one was true.

One way to work around this is to first check for `NULL` values and replace them with an empty string. Then use the `Contains` function on the results of this expression:

```
=IF(IsNothing(Fields!CMMTTEXT.Value), "", Fields!CMMTTEXT.Value).Contains("*Return*")
```